# Autodesk.NPR works with problems on mobiles

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using the Autodesk.NPR extension, and it functions correctly when accessed from a computer browser. However, when I access it from a mobile device, it produces an unusual effect. Is there a way to resolve this issue specifically for mobile devices?

**Desktop result**

[image]

**Mobile result**

[image]

The applied code is below:

```
await window.privateViewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.NPR")
const ext = window.privateViewer.getExtension('Autodesk.NPR').nprRenderContextExtension;

ext.setPostProcessParameter("style", 'edging');
ext.setPostProcessParameter("brightness", 0);
ext.setPostProcessParameter("contrast", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mobile devices are a bit tricky, since they have such a diverse set of GPU quirks in the browser.

NPR is mostly a 'post process shader' thing, which means, if there's a problem with the GPU support Powers of 2 textures, or precision issues, it's hard to track down.

This is definitely a 'precision issue', looking at the artifacts.

Quick question, to help me track it down further...
what mobile device you are seeing the artifacts on?

Is it an iPhone 15 Max Pro with Safari Mobile, running latest LMV?
or an iPad IOS15.3, Google pixel 8 with Chrome, etc.